# Subquery statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in a Mysql DB 
One has a list of options (actions) identified with Action_ID 
the other list is of the Tasks based on these actions ( for different jobs and in various states of completion )

I need a list of actions excluding the tasks already assigned to a specific job AND not yet completed .

i have these until now but get errors I did not manage to resolve yet :

```
    SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  Workshop_actions 
WHERE Action_ID IS NOT 
  (SELECT 
    Action_ID 
  FROM
    `Workshop_tasks` 
  WHERE W_job_ID = $ Job_ID 
    AND STATUS <> "F")
```

Being $Job_ID the specific job and F the status for Finished

Comment: What is the question? You're getting errors? Show them to us!

Comment: the error is      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT Action_ID FROM `Workshop_tasks` WHERE W_job_ID = $Job_ID AND Status <> "' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Workshop_actions a
  LEFT
  JOIN Workshop_tasks
    ON t.action_id = a.action_id
   AND W_job_ID = $Job_ID 
   AND Status <> "F"
 WHERE t.action_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This works like a charm !! Thanks , I only had to ad the t behind Workshop_tasks